# Instance search fails with multiple solutions even though all solutions are equal

Tags: agda

Instance search requires that all found solutions are unique. According to the Agda wiki (https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/instance-arguments.html, bottom of the page),

> From the previous stage we get a list of potential solutions. If the list is empty we fail with an error saying that no instance for C vs could be found (*no*). If there is a single solution we use it to solve the goal (*yes*), and if there are multiple solutions we check if they are all equal. If they are, we solve the goal with one of them (*yes*), but if they are not, we postpone instance resolution (*maybe*), hoping that some of the *maybes* will turn into *nos* once we know more about the involved metavariables.

Here I have some code that uses rose trees of bools. There are two data structures `Trues` and `Falses` that witness that the contents of a rose tree is all true or all false, respectively. There is also a function `Opp` that swaps all trues to falses and vice-versa. Naturally, `Trues x -> Falses (Opp x)` and vice-versa, so I wrote a function `OppTF` to witness this. However, Agda now complains that there are two ways to prove `Falses (B [])`, either directly with the constructor for `Falses`, or via the function `OppTF`. Of course, both of these produce the same result, and I prove this with the `uniq` function that proves that if `p : Trues (B [])` then `p` is unique. Nevertheless, Agda does not realise this.

How can I convince Agda that all solutions are equal? Unfortunately I cannot make the proof irrelevant with `.{{ _ : Falses x }}` as I need it later on. So I need to do one of the following:

- Coax Agda into fully normalising both candidate solutions, which will reveal they are equal.
- Use the `uniq` proof to convince Agda that all solutions are equal.
- Make Agda stop caring about duplicate solutions, without making the argument irrelevant.

Is it possible to do any of these, and if so, how?

Code and error below:

```
module Example where

open import Data.List
open import Data.Bool
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

data Rose : Set where
    V : Bool → Rose
    B : List Rose → Rose

Opp : Rose → Rose
Opp' : List Rose → List Rose

Opp (V x) = V (not x)
Opp (B xs) = B (Opp' xs)

Opp' [] = []
Opp' (x ∷ xs) = Opp x ∷ Opp' xs

data Trues : Rose → Set
data Trues' : List Rose → Set

data Trues where
    instance VTrues : Trues (V true)
    instance TTrues : ∀ {ts} ⦃ _ : Trues' ts ⦄ → Trues (B ts)
    
data Trues' where
    instance VTrues' : Trues' []
    instance TTrues' : ∀ {t ts} ⦃ _ : Trues t ⦄ ⦃ _ : Trues' ts ⦄ → Trues' (t ∷ ts)

data Falses : Rose → Set
data Falses' : List Rose → Set

data Falses where
    instance VFalses : Falses (V false)
    instance TFalses : ∀ {ts} ⦃ _ : Falses' ts ⦄ → Falses (B ts)
    
data Falses' where
    instance VFalses' : Falses' []
    instance TFalses' : ∀ {t ts} ⦃ _ : Falses t ⦄ ⦃ _ : Falses' ts ⦄ → Falses' (t ∷ ts)

instance
    OppTF : ∀ {x} ⦃ _ : Trues x ⦄ → Falses (Opp x)
    OppTF' : ∀ {xs} ⦃ _ : Trues' xs ⦄ → Falses' (Opp' xs)

    OppTF {x} ⦃ VTrues ⦄ = VFalses
    OppTF {x} ⦃ TTrues ⦃ xs ⦄ ⦄ = TFalses ⦃ OppTF' ⦃ xs ⦄ ⦄

    OppTF' {[]} ⦃ VTrues' ⦄ = VFalses'
    OppTF' {x ∷ xs} ⦃ TTrues' ⦃ p ⦄ ⦃ ps ⦄ ⦄ = TFalses' ⦃ OppTF ⦃ p ⦄ ⦄ ⦃ OppTF' ⦃ ps ⦄ ⦄

data Str : Rose → Set where
    Tor : ∀ {x : Rose} → Str x

dummy : ∀ {x : Rose} ⦃ _ : Falses x ⦄ → Rose
dummy {x} = x

test : Rose
test = dummy {B []}

uniq : ∀ {p : Falses (B [])} → p ≡ TFalses ⦃ VFalses' ⦄
uniq {TFalses {_} ⦃ VFalses' ⦄} = refl
```

Error:

```
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  Resolve instance argument _70 : Falses (B [])
  Candidates
    TFalses : {ts : List Rose} ⦃ _ : Falses' ts ⦄ → Falses (B ts)
    OppTF : {x : Rose} ⦃ _ : Trues x ⦄ → Falses (Opp x)
    (stuck)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved over on the Zulip chat with the option

`{-# OPTIONS --overlapping-instances #-}`

In this particular case, allowing overlapping instances doesn't cause a slowdown, however in my actual use-case it did, so also adding

`{-# OPTIONS --overlapping-instances --instance-search-depth 10 #-}`

greatly sped it up (the default search depth is 500).

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want more control over the (instance) search, you can typically move the decision into `Dec` (or even `Maybe`). You can then prove e.g. `decide : Dec (A + B)` from `Dec A` and `Dec B`, and add an implicit `True decide` to the instance, avoiding the overlap. (I can't guarantee this preserves performance :)